# Column has varbinary(max) but exception "value violates the MaxLength limit" is raised

Tags: c#, sql, varbinary

We have a Database with a Table called "Images", this Table has the column "ImageData"[varbinary(max)], and some other columns.

Now, when trying to add a binary value of the image as the value of the "ImageData" column, following exception is raised:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot set column 'ImageData'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.
```

How is this possible, if the size is "max" ?

Additional information:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(ImageData)
FROM OurDatabase.dbo.Images
```

returns for the biggest image a size of 500000, so its way below 2GB (varbinary max)

Comment: Seems like the error is raised when trying to add new data to the table. As such, running a query over existing data in the table doesn't give us any information. What's relevant is the size of the data that you're trying to add.

Comment: Seems like a product specific issue. Tag the dbms used to get better attention!

Comment: That isn't a SQL Server error. Looks like something in your ADO.NET code has a max length set.